# c# CefSharp browser cant most sites

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

Hi basically what the title says.

I am trying to have twitch open and play a video inside my application.

settings are

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
        if (Cef.IsInitialized) { }
        else
        {
            settings.SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs();
            //settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-vsync", "1");
            //settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
        }
```

xml code

```
<Grid>
    <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Name="chrome"  Address="www.twitch.tv" />
</Grid>
```

twitch basically just doesn't load, i have left it there for over an hour and it never came up, using google instead loads the page in about 10 seconds.
I have looked through their wiki, Youtube and Stackoverflow and i cant seen to find a way to speed up the loading.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Install pepper flash. Google for more information

Answer (score -1):

Ensure, that `CefSingleProcess` is set to `True`.

Comment: Cefsharp does not support single process mode.